# C# MailKit get messages conversation/replies inside treeview

Tags: c#, mailkit

i'm trying to replicate the view of a mailbox, i try to use references and threads but don't work, somethimes thread has uniqueid null.

```
   foreach (var rfr in Message.References ?? new MimeKit.MessageIdList())
        {
            var _uids = Imap.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.HeaderContains("Message-Id", rfr));

            if (_uids.Count > 0)
            {
                var _messages = Imap.Inbox.Fetch(_uids.ToList(), MessageSummaryItems.Envelope | MessageSummaryItems.Flags).OrderByDescending(o => o.Date);

                foreach (var msg in _messages)
                {
                    _Added.Add(msg.UniqueId);

                    RequestModel _model = new RequestModel
                    {
                        Address = msg.Envelope.From.Mailboxes.FirstOrDefault().Name ?? msg.Envelope.From.Mailboxes.FirstOrDefault().Address,
                        Subject = msg.Envelope.Subject,
                        Date = msg.Date.ToLocalTime().ToString(),
                        IsSeen = msg.Flags.Value.HasFlag(MailKit.MessageFlags.Seen),
                        Childs = new List<Scratch.MainWindow.RequestModel>(),
                    };

                    _retValue.Add(_model);
                }
            }
        }

var _messages = _imapClient.Inbox.Fetch(_uids.ToList(), MessageSummaryItems.Envelope | MessageSummaryItems.Flags | MessageSummaryItems.References).OrderByDescending(o => o.Date).Take(50);
            var _threads = MessageThreader.Thread(_messages, ThreadingAlgorithm.References);
```

Comment: http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/P_MailKit_MessageThread_UniqueId.htm - did you read the documentation?

Comment: Yes i read, but the message is inside the folder, is showed after in the list not ad child

Comment: You'd have to send me a sample test case that shows me exactly what you are talking about.

Comment: Take a look at MailKit's UnitTests for MessageThreader for hints on how to write a simple program that illustrates what you are seeing and I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MessageThreader` class uses the `References` (which contin a list of `Message-Id` values tracing back to the root of the thread) in order to construct the tree of messages. Obviously, if the list of message summaries that you give to the `MessageThreader` are missing some of those references, then the returned tree will have some empty nodes. This is why some of said nodes have a `null` `UniqueId` value.

FWIW, a few tips for you:

1. Don't do `_uids.ToList()` - `_uids` is *already* an `IList<UniqueId>`, why duplicate it for no reason?
2. It's more efficient to use the `orderBy` argument to `MessageThreader`.

Like this:

```
var orderBy = new OrderBy[] { OrderBy.ReverseDate };
var threads = MessageThreader.Thread (summaries, ThreadingAlgorithm.References, orderBy);
```